# Next JS slider using Next/Image rendering only the last image from the list

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am trying to create an image slider in Next.js using the Image component. I am looping over a list of images, and I am using the key prop to ensure that the images are displayed in the correct order. However, when I use the fill prop to resize the images to fill the width of their container, only the last image is visible.
This is how I loop over the slides:

```
<div className="relative overflow-hidden rounded-2xl">
        <div className="flex transition-transform duration-1000 ease-out aspect-square"
          style={{
            transform: `translateX(-${curr * 100}%)`,
          }}>
          {listing.slides.map((slide, i) => (
            <Image src={slide} key={i} fill />
          ))}
        </div>
</div>
```

`listing.slides` contains links to the images, which are hosted on Unsplash, I made sure that the website is whitelisted in next.config.js.

[Slide First: (which is actually supposed to be the last)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJBNb.png)
[All the other slides:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87ZUo.png)

I'm using functions prev() and next() to switch through the images:

```
  const [curr, setCurr] = useState(0);

  const prev = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    setCurr((curr) =>
      curr === 0 ? listing.slides.length - 1 : curr - 1
    );
  };
  const next = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    setCurr((curr) =>
      curr === listing.slides.length - 1 ? 0 : curr + 1
    );
  };
```

Using regular  tag works with no issues.

I have tried specifying the with and height props to specify the size of the images, but this results in the images appearing [stacked together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydDRw.png).